# Draw a square orthogonal to a vector3 (three.js)

Tags: three.js, linear-algebra, vector-graphics

As the title says, I'm trying to draw a square at the end of a vector.
My vector starts on the surface of a sphere (`radius = 1`) with location defined by `lat` and `long`.
For testing, I'm projecting the `vector3` to a point in space at `(4,4,4)` and want to have a square (plane) at the end point (say `(4,4,4)`).  The square needs to be *orthogonal* to this vector, or any other vectors defined by position on the sphere surface to a point in space.

Concept Image (Red is what I want to make)

[image: Concept Image]

---

The following code generates my vector in space, but I am struggling with the square part.
(I already know how to draw a square, just dont know how to put it at the end of the `vector3` code)

```
x1=4;
y1=4;
z1=4;
lat = 40;
lon = -70;
radius = 1;
x = -((radius) * Math.sin(phi)*Math.cos(theta));
z = ((radius) * Math.sin(phi)*Math.sin(theta));
y = ((radius) * Math.cos(phi));

var geometry3 = new THREE.Geometry();
var mygeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var material3 = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 });
geometry3.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));
geometry3.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x1, y1, z1));

var line1 = new THREE.Line(geometry3, material3);
scene.add(line1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match the normal of a plane mesh, to an arbitrary line you can use `mesh.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors( normal_of_plane, normalized_line_vector )`.

You can look at the documentation of quaternion at:  http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Quaternion